# Viewport Shading, color wont show up on the 3d object in cycle render

Tags: uv, image

Problem Resolved

[image]

i was following a tutorial online on how to make something and when it came time to add color to it i followed just how he did it. when he added an image into the texture node even when it wasn't attached to any other node it got color to it. but when i added mine no matter what color i had in it, my 3d object would just turn white. i tried attaching the texture node to the color attachment on the diffuse BSDF node but it still stayed white. can anyone help?

Comment: Change to Textured shading, Alt+Z

Comment: To see a texture in 3D viewport, change the Viewport Shading type to Material or Rendered. Right now you have Solid enabled.